# Azure DeployIfNotExist Policy evalutes but do not deploy template/show compliant

Tags: azure, policy

I am working on DeployIfNotExist Azure Policy which checks all vnets, checks if specific peering exists and if so checks UDR settings in place. If different than specified, it aims to deploy required UDR.

I am not able to get this to work and the current state is that initial check works fine (non-compliant vnets are reported) but no automatic remediation is done for new/updated vnets. Further, if I do manual remediation, the vnet is still marked as non-compliant.

Azure Policy Policy Rule below.

```
{
  "if": {
      "anyOf": [
          {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "type",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VirtualNetworkPeerings[*].peeringState",
                    "equals": "Connected"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VirtualNetworkPeerings[*].name",
                    "equals": "peerSpokeToHub"
                }
            ]
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "type",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VirtualNetworkPeerings"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/remoteVirtualNetwork.id",
                    "exists": "true"
                }
            ]
          }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
          "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
          "details": {
              "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
              "existenceCondition": {
                  "allOf": [
                      {
                          "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/routeTable.id",
                          "exists": "true"
                      },
                      {
                          "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/routeTable.routes[*].name",
                          "equals": "toNVA"
                      },
                      {
                          "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/routeTable.routes[*].addressPrefix",
                          "equals": "0.0.0.0/0"
                      },
                      {
                          "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/routeTable.routes[*].nextHopType",
                          "equals": "VirtualAppliance"
                      },
                      {
                          "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/routeTable.routes[*].nextHopIpAddress",
                          "in": ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]
                      },
                      {
                          "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/routeTable.routes[*].provisioningState",
                          "equals": "Succeeded"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              "roleDefinitionIds": [
                  "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
              ],
              "deployment": {
                  "properties": {
                      "mode": "incremental",
                      "template": {
                        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                        "parameters": {
                          "vNetName": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "metadata": {
                              "description": "subnet to attach udr"
                            }
                          },
                          "RouteTableName": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "metadata": {
                              "description": "Name of a route table upon remediation"
                            }
                          },
                          "location": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "metadata": {
                              "description": "location of resource"
                            }
                          },
                          "NVAip": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "metadata": {
                              "description": "NVA IP"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "resources": [
                          {
                            "name": "[parameters('RouteTableName')]",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
                            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "properties": {
                              "routes": [
                                {
                                  "properties": {
                                    "addressPrefix": "0.0.0.0/0",
                                    "nextHopType": "VirtualAppliance",
                                    "nextHopIpAddress": "[parameters('NVAip')]"
                                  },
                                  "name": "toNVA"
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
                            "name": "apply-routetable-to-subnet",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
                            "resourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().name]",
                            "dependsOn": [
                              "[concat('Microsoft.Network/routeTables/', 'RouteTable')]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                              "mode": "Incremental",
                              "template": {
                                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                                "resources": [
                                  {
                                    "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
                                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
                                    "name": "[concat(parameters('vNetName'),'/default')]",
                                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                                    "properties": {
                                      "addressPrefix": "[reference(resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vNetName'), 'default'), '2018-03-01').addressPrefix]",
                                      "routeTable": {
                                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', parameters('RouteTableName'))]"
                                      },
                                      "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                        "id": "[reference(resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vNetName'), 'default'), '2018-03-01').networkSecurityGroup.id]"
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      "parameters": {
                          "vNetName":    {
                            "value": "[field('fullName')]"
                          },
                          "RouteTableName": {
                            "value": "[parameters('RouteTableName')]"
                          },
                          "NVAip": {
                            "value": "[parameters('fortigateIp')]"
                          },
                          "location": {
                            "value": "[field('location')]"
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: What does the remediation tab show when you go there on Azure portal? Normally there is a state indicating success/failure with information about the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a problem with your ARM template. I would be sure to test it and check it. The ARM VSCode extension now has a what-if testing capability that lets you see what happens when you are to deploy that template.